# Pipe character ignored in SPSS syntax

Tags: spss

I am trying to use the pipe character "|" in SPSS syntax with strange results:

In the syntax it appears like this:
[image]
But when I copy this line from the syntax window to here, this is what I get:
`SELECT IF(SEX = 1  SEX = 2).`
The pipe just disappears!

If I run this line, this is the output:

> SELECT IF(SEX = 1  SEX = 2).
>
> Error # 4007 in column 20.  Text: SEX 
>   The expression is incomplete.  Check for missing operands, invalid operators, 
>   unmatched parentheses or excessive string length. 
>   Execution of this command stops.
>   So the pipe is invisible to the program too!

When I save this syntax and reopen it, the pipe is gone...

The only way I found to get SPSS to work with the pipe is when I edited the syntax (adding the pipe) and saved it in an alternative editor (notepad++ in this case). Now, without opening the syntax, I ran it from another syntax using `insert` command, and it worked.

EDIT: some background info:
I have spss version 23 (+service pack 3) 64 bit.
The same things happens if I use my locale (encoding: windows-1255) or Unicode (Encoding: UTF-8). Suspecting my Hebrew keyboard I tried copying syntax from the web with same results.

Can anyone shed any light on this subject?

Comment: The pipe character in your screenshot looks odd. Since you're using windows-1255 encoding, I suspect you typed a Hebrew Punctuation Paseq (U+05C0 in Unicode) instead of a Vertical line (U+007C). If you run the code, the paseq is not interpreted as a valid operator and spss returns an error. It is unclear to me why the character disappears from the file after saving it. It could be related to chosen locale writing system, the locale setting, the bidirectional text setting? Or it could be a bug related to translation between different encodings. Have you installed the latest fix packs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out (according to SPSS support) that's a version specific (ver. 21) bug and was fixed in later versions.